# "after" looping indefinitely: never entering mainloop

Tags: python, event-handling, tkinter, tetris

This is my first post. I started coding when considering a career swap two months ago and am working on a Tetris clone. I've implemented most of the core features, but cannot get the game to refresh continually with an after loop.

I'm using Tkinter to produce my Gui and am trying out event oriented programming.

My understanding is that `after(Time, Event)` from `Tkinter` should schedule whatever the `Event` callback function is to occur after a delay specified by `Time`. I think that the code is supposed to continue executing subsequent items after this.

My frame refresh function (`game.updateBoard()`) does most of the necessary events for tetris to work, then calls itself using after. I call it once when initializing an instance of the game.

Instead of proceeding to `mainloop()`, the `game.updateboard()` function calls itself via `after` indefinitely.

I suspect that it is not behaving how I thought `after` worked which would be to continue to execute the script until the specified delay occurs. I think it is waiting for the callback to terminate to continue.

I tried to find a resource on this but could not.

If you have suggestions for fixing this question, the attached code, or for coding in general, I am very happy to hear them! This is a learning process and I'll gladly try pretty much anything you suggest.

Here is the relevant portion of the code:

```
class game():
    def __init__(self): #Set up board and image board
        self.pieces = ["L","J","S","Z","T","O","I"]
        self.board = boardFrame()
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title("Tetris")
        self.root.geometry("250x525")

        self.frame = Frame(self.root)

        #set up black and green squares for display
        self.bSquare = "bsquare.gif"
        self.gSquare = "square.gif"
        self.rSquare = "rsquare.gif"
        self.image0 = PhotoImage(file = self.bSquare)
        self.image1 = PhotoImage(file = self.gSquare)
        self.image2 = PhotoImage(file = self.rSquare)

        #get an initial piece to work with
        self.activeBlock = piece(self.pieces[random.randint(0,6)])

        #Tells program to lower block every half second
        self.blockTimer = 0
        self.updateBoard()

        self.root.bind('<KeyPress-Up>', self.turn)
        self.root.bind('<KeyPress-Right>', self.moveR)
        self.root.bind('<KeyPress-Left>', self.moveL)
        self.root.bind('<KeyPress-Down>',self.moveD)
        print("Entering mainloop")
        self.root.mainloop()

    def turn(self, event):
        self.activeBlock.deOccupy(self.board)
        self.activeBlock.turn()
        self.activeBlock.occupy(self.board)
        self.drawGrid(self.board.grid)

    def moveR(self, event):
        self.activeBlock.deOccupy(self.board)
        self.activeBlock.updatePos([1,0], self.board)
        self.activeBlock.occupy(self.board)
        self.drawGrid(self.board.grid)

    def moveL(self, event):
      if self.activeBlock.checkLeft(self.board) == False:
        self.activeBlock.deOccupy(self.board)
        self.activeBlock.updatePos([-1,0], self.board)
        self.activeBlock.occupy(self.board)
        self.drawGrid(self.board.grid)

    def moveD(self, event): #find
        self.activeBlock.deOccupy(self.board)
        self.activeBlock.updatePos([0,-1],self.board)
        if self.activeBlock.checkBottom(self.board) == True:
            self.activeBlock.occupy(self.board)
            self.activeBlock = piece(self.pieces[random.randint(0,6)])
##            self.activeBlock = piece(self.pieces[1])
            print("bottomed")
            self.activeBlock.occupy(self.board)

        self.activeBlock.occupy(self.board)
        self.drawGrid(self.board.grid)

    def drawGrid(self, dGrid):

        #Generate squares to match tetris board
        for widget in self.frame.children.values():
            widget.destroy()

        self.activeBlock.occupy(self.board)

        for x in range(9,-1,-1):
            for y in range(20,-1,-1):
                if self.board.grid[x][y] == 1:
                    self.frame.displayA = Label(self.frame, image=self.image1)
##                    self.frame.displayA.image = self.image1
                    self.frame.displayA.grid(row=21-y, column=x)


                else:
                    self.frame.displayA = Label(self.frame, image = self.image0)
##                    self.frame.displayA.image = self.image0
                    self.frame.displayA.grid(row=21-y, column=x)

        self.frame.displayA = Label(self.frame, image = self.image2)
        self.frame.displayA.grid(row = 21 - self.activeBlock.center[1], column = self.activeBlock.center[0])

        self.frame.grid()

    def updateBoard(self):
        self.blockTimer += 1
        "print updateBoard Loop"

        ## 1)check for keyboard commands
        #1.1 move block by keyboard commands
        #2) see if block has bottomed out, if it has, have it enter itself into the grid and generate a new block.
        if self.activeBlock.checkBottom(self.board) == True:
            self.activeBlock.occupy(self.board)
            self.activeBlock = piece(self.pieces[random.randint(0,6)])
            print("bottomed")
            self.activeBlock.occupy(self.board)

        #2.2 - if block has not bottomed and 50 frames (~.5 seconds) have passed, move the active block down a square after clearing its old space. 
        elif self.blockTimer%12 == 0:
            self.activeBlock.deOccupy(self.board)
            self.activeBlock.updatePos([0,-1], self.board)
            self.activeBlock.occupy(self.board)


    ## 4) check for filled rows
        for y in range(1,21):
            for x in range(10):
                rowFull = True
                if self.board.grid[x][y] == 0:
                    rowFull == False  
            #4.1 if any row is filled, delete it and then move all rows above the deleted row down by one
            if rowFull == True:
                for x2 in range(10):
                    self.board.grid[x2][y] = 0
                    for y2 in range(y+1,21):
                        if self.board.grid[x2][y2] == 1:
                            self.board.grid[x2][y2] = 0
                            self.board.grid[x2][y2-1] = 1

            #4.11 if the row is full and the row above it was full, delete the row again as well as the row above it, and move all rows down by 2
                for x in range(10):
                    rowFull = True
                    if self.board.grid[x][y] == 0:
                        rowFull == False
                        if rowFull == True:
                            for x2 in range(10):
                                try:
                                    self.board.grid[x2][y] = 0
                                    self.board.grid[x2][y+1] = 0
                                except:
                                    pass
                                for y2 in range(y+2,21):
                                    try:
                                        if self.board.grid[x2][y2] == 1:
                                            self.board.grid[x2][y2] = 0
                                            self.board.grid[x2][y2-2] = 1
                                    except:
                                        pass


        #5) if there is a block in the top row, end the game loop
        for x in range(10):
            if self.board.grid[x][20] == 1:
                game = "over"


        #6) update image
        self.activeBlock.occupy(self.board)
        self.drawGrid(self.board.grid)
        self.frame.after(500, self.updateBoard())


Game = game()
```

Comment: Tim: don't forget to accept @mgilson's answer as "correct".

Comment: Thanks for the heads up js. I did not realize that was what I was supposed to do.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You want to do `self.frame.after(500, self.updateBoard)`.

The difference here is subtle, (`self.updateBoard` instead of `self.updateBoard()`).  In your version, you're passing the *result of your function* to the `after` method instead of passing the *function*.  This results in the infinite recursion that you described.

Comment: Wow thanks mgilson! That definitely entered the mainloop. What is the difference between the call self.updateBoard and self.updateBoard()? Is this a python wide one or unique to the Tkinter library?

Comment: +1.  Your answer is absolutely correct and does not need to be qualified by "I think that ...".

Comment: @TimWilder:  This is not specific to Tkinter.  The parenthesis cause the function to be called (and therefore the return value of the function is passed as an argument).  You want to instead pass the function itself as an argument so Tkinter can call it later.

Comment: The result versus function pass distinction makes perfect sense. I hadn't passed a function to anything before. This information will be useful.

Comment: @TimWilder -- `self.updateBoard()` causes the function to be called and returns the result.  `self.updateBoard` is just a reference to the function object.  It is important to realize that python functions are objects just like everything else.  Tkinter's `after` method takes a *reference* to the function and then calls that reference for you after the specified amount of time.

Comment: Ugh! I just fell for this, but didn't even realize it! If you pass any args to your callback, pass them to `after` as the 3rd, 4th, &c. arguments. EG `after(100, callback, arg1, arg2, arg3, ...)` See [Effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) or [New Mexico Tech](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html)

Comment: @MarkMikofski -- Yep, or, if you forget that you can pass extra args to after, you can use a lambda:  `after(100,lambda: callback(arg1,arg2,...))`.  Your version's probably better though -- I just always end up using a million lambdas when programming with Tkinter.