# Infinite loop in Tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, python-2.7, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am having a problem running a loop that will auto update some stuff. (Like game money) It is supposed to add 100 dollars every 30 seconds. The Gui won't load, but the shell does not give me any errors. Thanks in advance!

```
def update():
    while True:
        money = money + 100
        label.set(str(money))
        time.sleep(30)
```

Comment: This is probably the same problem as was solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043693/python-and-tkinter-aftermilliseconds-event-looping-indefinitely-never-enteri

Answer (score 2):

Try writing your function this way instead. You should be scheduling your code to run, not looping it.

```
def update(money=0, increase=100, repeat=30):
    money += increase
    label.set(money)
    label._master.after(repeat * 1000, update, money, increase, repeat)
```

Comment: Thanks! Do i have to import any modules for this, and do I call the function with empty parameters?

Comment: Basically my label is a StringVar() instance, and my code says that StringVar has no attribute .after().  Is there any way that you know how to fix this? (without seeing more code)

Comment: @user2556952: Did you forget the `._master.after(` part?