# Python 3.x Tkinter Serial Reading

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, serial-port

I am having difficulty reading serial data coming from an arduino over a serial connection. In order to get around the issue of serial and the gui needing to be running simultansouly, I am using the .after function to call the update serial every 100ms. However, when I run this code, I get no window popping up, and I get an error saying I have exceeded the max recursion depth. Here is my code:

```
'''
Created on Nov 23, 2014

@author: Charlie
'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass

import serial
from tkinter import *

ser = serial.Serial('COM8')
ser.baudrate = 9600

def update():
    c = StringVar()
    c=ser.readline()
    theta.set(c)
    root.after(100,update())

root=Tk()
theta = StringVar()

w = Label(root, textvariable = theta)
w.pack()

root.after(100,update())    
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `root.after(100, update)`. Notice the lack of parentheses after `update`. Using the parentheses sends the result of `update` to the `after` call, but to calculate the result, `update` has to be run which contains another call to `after` which needs the result of `update` and so on..

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043693/python-and-tkinter-aftermilliseconds-event-looping-indefinitely-never-enteri).

Also, why do you make a new `StringVar` every time the `update` function is called?
`c = ser.readline()` overwrites `c` anyway, so you may just as well remove that line.

Answer (score -1):

In func `update()` remove cycle `root.after(100,update())`. This:

```
def update():
    c = StringVar()
    c=ser.readline()
    theta.set(c)
```

Comment: My intent is to reset the next call for update when I call that. Otherwise, wouldn't my update only get called Once? Once right before the call to main loop. There would be no infinite loop of calling it again and again.

Comment: If you're read to data in func `update()` to better update the label. This: 'w.after(100, update())', if you're func return the value.